Every EFA sufficient formalization of Con(σ) implies every usual formalization of Con(σ) in L(EFA), over EFA + Con(EFA).
I do not follow this argument from page 23 HERE;
THEOREM 0.1C.2. Let σ be a sentence in MSL. Every EFA
sufficient formalization of Con(σ) implies every usual
formalization of Con(σ) in L(EFA), over EFA + Con(EFA).
(Here Con(EFA) is any usual formalization of Con(EFA) in
L(EFA).)
Proof: Let ϕ be an EFA sufficient formalization of Con(σ).
Let M witness this assumption. We argue in EFA + Con(EFA) +
ϕ that σ is consistent in MSL. Let π be a proof of ¬σ in
MSL. By relativizing π to M, we obtain a proof in EFA of
$¬σ^M$. But we already have a proof in EFA of $σ^M$. Hence EFA is
inconsistent. Therefore π does not exist. Hence σ is
consistent. QED

I do not understand what is "over EFA + Con(EFA)"
What is M in Let M witness this assumption.

Hint:  I believe that M is some model in EFA.

The definition of "EFA sufficient formalization" involves the existence of some structure satisfying certain properties. $M$ is such a structure. One thing implying another thing "over EFA + Con(EFA)" means that the theory EFA + Con(EFA) proves the implication.

@spaceisdarkgreen Con(σ) implies Con(σ) is a tautology.

Two different formulations of Con($\sigma$) implying one another is not.
